# Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) stops working for me

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

my server was sending push notification without any problems till yesterday.
Then it stop without any changes made to server or code.

I use php on an ubuntu system to send the notifications.

Since yesterday I get this error, when connecting:

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

All certificates are sill valid.

Any idea, what could happend?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Same for us. This error seems to come and go.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped, to revoke all certificates, even if they are still valid and create them new.
After this, everything is now working again...